# Helm Chart Provenance check GnuPG command is not working on windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell, kubernetes-helm, gnupg, gpg-signature

We are using Helm chart and need to generate provenance file during packaging of chart, by using GnuPG. But GnuPG commands are not working into windows powershell and gives below error

When we export key to make keyring using gpg command in powershell it is creating invalid keyring packet.

gpg --batch --passphrase 'test#123' --quick-generate-key 'Provenance Key'

gpg --export-secret-keys >/seckey.gpg

[image]